# Bash: how to make a substitution in a "live" pipe?

Tags: perl, bash, pipe

In my office firewall I use a command like this:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -v -s 1500 -i eth0 port 25 | grep 'smtp: S'
```

to monitor LAN clients sending mail (I need to early detect any possible spammer bot from some client, we have very looooose security policies, here... :-().

So far, so good: I have a continuous output as soon any client sends an email.

*But*, if I add some filter to get a cleaner output, something like this:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -v -s 1500 -i eth0 port 25 | grep 'smtp: S' | perl -pe 's/(.*?\)) (.*?)\.\d+ \>(.*)/$2/'
```

(here I intend to get only source ip/name), I do not get any output until tcpdump output is more than (bash?) buffer size... (or at least I suppose so...).

Nothing changes using 'sed' instead of 'perl'...

Any hint to get a continuous output of filtered data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `stdbuf` before the first command:

```
sudo stdbuf -o0 tcpdump ...
```

Answer (score 2):

> But, if I add some filter to get a cleaner output, something like
>   this:

Use the `--line-buffered` option for `grep`:

```
   --line-buffered
          Use  line  buffering  on  output.   This can cause a performance
          penalty.
```

Answer (score 0):

try maybe a `sed --unbuffered` (or `-u` sometimes like on AIX) to have a stram version (not waiting the EOF)